# China approval for US company acquisition

Tags: usa, regulation, china, competition-authority

Why does China has to give approval to two US companies merging together?

There have been quite a few examples in the last time, as UTC & Rockwell Collins as well as Qualcomm acquiring NXP Semiconductor.

Why does in this case UTC need approval from China : https://edition.cnn.com/2018/11/27/business/united-technologies-breakup-conglomerate/index.html